# Build failed after changing UITextField for UITextView

Tags: ios, uitextfield, uitextview

In my app `storyBoard` I have changed a `UITextField` for a `UITextView`, and also in the header file.

I was using the former UITextField as follows:

```
[todoItemText addTarget:self action:@selector(textFieldDidChange) forControlEvents:UIControlEventEditingChanged];
```

And now, after changing the type to UITextView, the build fails showing the following message at the above mentioned line of code:

```
AddToDoItemViewController.m:86:19: No visible @interface for 'UITextView' declares the selector 'addTarget:action:forControlEvents:'
```

At the .h file I have this implementation:

```
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITextView *todoItemText;
```

And it is also synthetized in the .m file.

What have I done wrong?

Comment: @Zaph , I am using StoryBoard.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The compiler is correct. `UITextView` does not support that method. It's not a `UIControl` like `UITextField`.

Instead of adding such a target, set the text view's delegate and implement the `textViewDidChange:` delegate method.